# Polygonize black areas (0) in raster

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, rasterio

I have satellite imagery. Some of these images have black areas (zero values). I would like to polygonize the black areas. Is this possible using QGIS or rasterio?

[image: raster]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to do this with [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) using [rasterio.features.shapes](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.shapes)...

The resulting polygons around the black pixels are drawn hatched in the image below:

[image]

Note: my test image has also black pixels inside the image.

Sample code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import rasterio
import rasterio.plot
from rasterio import features
import shapely
from shapely.plotting import plot_polygon

path = "http://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/other/erdas_spnad83.tif"
value_to_keep = 0

result = []
with rasterio.open(path) as src:
    image = src.read(1)

    # create a binary image, 1 where value is value_to_keep, 0 for the rest
    is_valid = (image != value_to_keep).astype(np.uint8)

    # vectorize the binary image, supplying the transform so it returns map coords
    for coords, value in features.shapes(is_valid, transform=src.transform):
        # only keep polygons corresponding to value_to_keep
        if value == value_to_keep:
            # convert geojson to shapely geometry
            result.append(shapely.geometry.shape(coords))

    # Plot result
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = rasterio.plot.show(image, ax=ax, transform=src.transform, cmap="Greys_r")

    for geom in result:
        plot_polygon(geom, ax=ax, color="grey", add_points=False, hatch="/")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer since I need to iterate over a set of rasters.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite result, polygons which present the valid area of the image, can be achieved with the new GDAL utility gdal_footprint https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_footprint.html.

> The gdal_footprint utility can be used to compute the footprint of a
> raster file, taking into account nodata values (or more generally the
> mask band attached to the raster bands), and generating
> polygons/multipolygons corresponding to areas where pixels are valid,
> and write to an output vector file.

Polygons for the nodata areas can be created with the gdal_polygonize utility https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html. It may be useful to do preliminary step with gdal_nearblack https://gdal.org/programs/nearblack.html first.

The workflow:

1. If the image does not have an alpha band or a mask band, create a temporaty file that has by using the nearblack utility. Usage:

`nearblack -of GTiff -setalpha infile.tif -o temp_outfile.tif`

2. The final step is to polygonize the alpha or mask band. That band has only 2 different values which present data/nodata. Usage:

`gdal_polygonize -f GeoJSON -b mask temp_outfile.tif polygonized.json`

The polygonized.json file will have polygons for both nodata and data areas. There is an attribute field (DN by default) that can be used for selecting the data areas so they can be deleted later.

Comment: great, thank you!

Comment: hmm, when I type gdal_footprint input.tif  output.geojson -srcnodata 0  -split_polys, I only receive one geojson that covers the areas that have no black areas. Any clue?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question properly. Gdal_footprint is made for creating polygons which present the valid areas of the image. But your aim is the opposite, to create polygons from the non-valid pixels. I will improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you for improving your answer! When I run nearblack and load my raster, I get the error "ERROR 6: Too many command options 'temp_outfile.tif'". The raster just has one band (b1).

Comment: Sorry, `-o` was missing from the command.

Comment: it should be gdal_polyonize.py, right? because it does not find gdal_polyonize

Comment: Yes, this one https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html. It is a Python script but on Windows with the OSGeo4W installation it can be run as `gdal_polygonize`. Run it as required in your system. You need to have the script, GDAL Python bindings, and correct Python version installed.

Comment: One more alternative is to build this program https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts/blob/master/src/gdal_trace_outline.cc and run it with the -invert parameter "Trace no-data pixels rather than data pixels". The program is feature rich.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at it!